# Samba authentication using read-only LDAP server without samba attributes

Tags: ldap, authentication, samba

I have read-only access to an LDAP server which only stores unix account information (no samba attributes). I’d like to grant the users in the LDAP directory access to the samba shares on my server.

So every time a user wants to access a share, my server should check with the LDAP server whether his credentials are correct. Is this possible?

If I understand correctly, samba accounts must in this case be stored in another backend with their own samba password hashes, etc. If this is correct, I would assume that it is not possible to populate this backend with the data from the LDAP server due to different hashing algorithms. So how can I keep the databases synced?

I found a few similar questions on this site, but, unfortunately, could not find a solution to my problem so far...